# Accessing specific element of the singly linked list

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I want to make a function get_element(n) that returns an element of a singly linked list depending on the position of the element in the list. If I send -1 to the function, I want the last element to be returned, if it's -2, the function returns the second to the last element and so on. How can I do it without reversing the list or introducing additional attributes (size or similar)? If I want the second to the last I can do it with traversing the list until current.next.next == None, the third to the last with current.next.next.next == None, but I don't know how to generalize it.
I would appreciate it if someone could write me that piece of code in any language, in Python preferrably.

Comment: Keep a queue of the last `-n` elements visited and take its first element when you reach `None`. Nearly equivalent to reversing the list, but that’s really the only way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Python is probably not the best language to choose, as the functionality you want is already built in:

```
def get_element(n):
    my_list = ["The", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat."]
    return my_list[n]


print get_element(0)
print get_element(-1)
print get_element(-2)
```

Which would give:

```
The
mat.
the
```

As mentioned, you could simulate your problem using a queue:

```
import collections


def get_element(n):
    my_list = ["The", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat."]

    if n >= 0:
        for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
            if index == n:
                return element

        # Return last element if beyond the range
        return element  
    else:
        queue = collections.deque(maxlen=-n)    # Used to simulate a queue

        for element in my_list:
            queue.append(element)

        return queue.popleft()


print get_element(0)
print get_element(-1)
print get_element(-2)
```

Which would give:

```
The
mat.
the
```